# Is there a way to use youtube-dl to get the video url for the client on my web app by using Javascript or something else?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, django, youtube-dl

I am trying to extract the source urls from Dailymotion, Openload, and Google Video using youtube-dl.

I am fully aware that a url retrieved from one computer will not work on another because each link is IP/cookie/user agent specific as well as time sensitive. [source](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#i-extracted-a-video-url-with--g-but-it-does-not-play-on-another-machine--in-my-web-browser)

The issue with this approach is my attempt to retrieve the urls solely via the server. The solution would be if the client side was responsible for all the interactions and requests to retrieve the urls.

I am not well-versed in Javascript but I am confident that it is the solution to the above problem. I know of the existence of a node.js variety of youtube-dl but it isn't actively maintained, a dead end. [source](https://github.com/przemyslawpluta/node-youtube-dl)

There are node.js projects that are actively developed but only supports youtube. [source](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core)

Alltube, a web app variety of youtube-dl, used to be able to do this but has taken out the feature because it was too taxing to the server(?), mind you they used php server side to do this. [source](https://github.com/Rudloff/alltube/blob/c9990a208439029f4e0fee0b68512073dbbbc8c7/api.php#L119)

Does anyone know how to extract urls with Javascript for client side requests? Is there something other than youtube-dl that can accomplish this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @scientist.rahul Nothing yet. Youtube-dl only works only on the one IP. I think I heard that they were planning on building a Javascript variety as a workaround.

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem. There are many nodejs module implementations of youtube-dl. Planning to migrate them to pure javascript using browserify. Will post the update if it works. I guess it may work but may be too heavy to use on client side.